# Multiple conditions to select data of a frame in R

Tags: r

1. Load this dataset (just start R, because it is already loaded by default):

   airquality
2. Here, there are the columns `Ozone Solar.R Wind Temp Month Day` with 153 observations.
3. I want to select a combination of the following:

   - Ozone > 50
   - Solar.R > 50
   - be defined (id est, drop the NAs).

I tried in R's console `airquality[airquality$O > 50 && airquality$S > 50,]`, but the result is wrong.

Q: How to return the rows that have the good entries ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is an approach that uses `subset` (which is recommended only for interactive use, which is what you describe):

```
subset(airquality[complete.cases(airquality), ], Ozone > 50 & Solar.R > 50)
```

The idea here is to first drop the `NA`s with `complete.cases`, then to subset based on your conditions.

---

Sticking with `[` notation, I suppose you could also do it in two steps, as below:

```
temp <- with(airquality, airquality[Ozone > 50 & Solar.R > 50, ])
temp[complete.cases(temp), ]
```